# Access multiple collections in morphia

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am using morphia to pull data from mongodb. I will be only reading the data from mongodb and not writing in it. 
I have created a single model class which will have all fields in the collection.
I will have multiple collections in db and the count can increase.
I am using @Entity("collection name") to map the collection.
My problem is: I will require data from different collections. So how do I map it. The collection name passed to @Entity should be dynamic or is there any other way.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi I am author of play-morphia plugin. Your requirement is exactly one use case of the planned feature multi-tenant support. Unfortunately I have no time to work on that so far and I can't commit when it will be ready

Answer (score 0):

You're working with Java, so, unfortunately, there are no easy alternatives.

Your best bet, IMHO, would be to write a script which generates all of the appropriate files from a template file, and run the script every time an entity is added/removed from your collection.

Your second best bet is to use Java's reflection facilities to generate the equivalent classes on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will try to use java reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Are there a fixed number of collections? If so, I believe you could create one abstract class with all the fields and then create a subclass for each collection each with the @Entity annotation filled in with the corresponding collection name.

Comment: Yes the number of collections are not fixed.